# Дата послезавтрашнего дня в javascript

Tags: дата, jquery

Всем добрый день!
Вопрос такой. Как с помощью метода Date() получить дату послезавтрашнего дня? (js/jQuery)

Comment:     var dayAfterTomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

Answer (score 1):

вот так:

```
var poslezavtra=new Date(new Date().getTime()+172800000);
```

если надо начало дня(локального), то нужно добавить

```
poslezavtra.setHours(0);
poslezavtra.setMinutes(0);
poslezavtra.setSeconds(0);
```

[тут описание объекта Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)